# Segmentation fault using pthread on /proc

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm creating a certain number of pthread on a specific event. Every pthread make a scan of /proc but after a while i receive segmentation fault. I really appreciate if someone help me

**Cycle on pthread function where i get segmentation fault**

```
while ((topproc_dent = readdir(topproc_dir)) != NULL)
{
  if (topproc_dent->d_name[0] < '0' || topproc_dent->d_name[0] > '9') /* Not a process */
    continue;
  pid = atoi(topproc_dent->d_name);
  /* Dont analize my_self */
  if (pid == my_pid)
    continue;

  snprintf(strPath, sizeof strPath, "%s%jd%s", "/proc/", (intmax_t) pid, "/fd");

  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;
  printf("%s\n", strPath);
  dp = opendir(strPath);
  if (dp != NULL)
  {
    while (ep = readdir(dp))
    {
      if (strcmp("..", ep->d_name) == 0)
        continue;
      if (strcmp(".", ep->d_name) == 0)
        continue;
      snprintf(strLink, sizeof strPath, "%s%s%s", strPath, "/", ep->d_name);
      printf("%s\n", strLink);
      if ((len = readlink(strLink, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) != -1)
        buf[len] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    (void) closedir(dp);
  }
  else
    perror("Couldn't open the directory");
  closedir(dp);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need so many space for that code ?

Comment: Do you `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` or `pthread_attr_setdetachedstate()`? No? Do you check `pthread_create()` for failure? Are you aware that `readdir()` is not thread-safe?

Comment: @EOF I didn't know readdir is not thread safe, how i can avoid the problem? Any ideas? For the other function i can't use 'pthread_join()' because for each event i need a different scan of '/proc' and every thread don't exit from this cycle so it can't call 'pthread_deatach'

Comment: You *must* either set the pthreads to be detached, or join with them, otherwise they are not cleaned up when they exit, potentially preventing further `pthread_create()`s from succeeding. Also, for every function you call, you *must* know whether it is thread-safe or not, and arrange for proper synchronization if it isn't. In the case of `readdir()`, there is a thread-safe replacement, `readdir_r()`.

Comment: As EOF mentioned above, [`readdir_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir_r.3.html) is the POSIX.1 thread-safe version. You could also switch to POSIX.1-2008 [`scandir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) instead. ([`glob()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) is thread safe only if you do not access utmp or modify environment or use the sigalrm concurrently -- I would not recommend using `glob()` in a multithreaded program.)